# I want to add three button using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to create "button 02" by clicking on "Button 01", after that create "button 03" by clicking on "Button 02"

I tried with follow codes

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 
     $(".btnone").click(function(){
   var btntwostr= '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btntwo" >Button 02</button>';
   $("#btntwodiv").html(btntwostr);
  });
  
  $(".btntwo").click(function(){
   var btnthreestr= '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btnttree" >Button 02</button>';
   $("#btnthreediv").html(btnthreestr);
  });
  
     
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btnone" >Button 01</button>
<div id="btntwodiv"></div>
<div id="btnthreediv"></div>
```

first step is OK, but second step doesn't work, Please help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is that you bind to an element that doesn't exist yet, so you can either do as @PeteTNT suggests, or use the [jquery .on handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/), this helps you bind to elements that does't yet exist.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btnone").click(function(){
        var btntwostr= '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btntwo" >Button 02</button>';
        $("#btntwodiv").html(btntwostr);
    });

    $(document).on('click', ".btntwo", function(){
        var btnthreestr= '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btnttree" >Button 02</button>';
        $("#btnthreediv").html(btnthreestr);
    });


});
```

Do note that there are alot of ways you can achieve this functionality in a more scalable way. And I will suggest you look into refactoring that code.